# Dispatcher Servlet. Where does it fit in in the Spring MVC framework

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I read about the Dispatcher Servlet on the Spring Source website.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

My question is where does the Dispatcher Servlet fit in in the MVC framework. If we see the diagram in the above description, it is seen as distinct from both the Controller and the View. It obviously cannot be a part of the Model. So how does it fit in the MVC framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's still part of the controller layer. In that diagram it's given a separate distinction from the other controllers and labeled as a "front controller," which simply delegates incoming requests to the other controllers and handles the interaction with the view.

The alternative would be to remove it and have individual controllers process their own requests.

So, it's still a controller, it just happens to be delegating the work to other controllers and then handling the interaction with the view.